# .htaccess rewrite rules for multiple parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-routing

Rewriting the following 3 URLs

`http://example.com/index.php?page=search`
to 
`http://example.com/search`

`http://example.com/index.php?page=profile&value=myname`
to 
`http://example.com/myname`

`http://example.com/index.php?page=stats&type=daily`
to 
`http://example.com/stats/daily`

Current .htaccess is written as the following:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+)&value=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index/%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+)&type=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index/%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index/%1/? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^index/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&value=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^index/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&type=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^index/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

I need to remove /index/ from the first and third URL, and /index/profile/ from the second one.

All comments & suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: There is a problem with your current .htaccess rules in that you are redirecting both `page=X&value=Y` and `page=X&type=Y` to the same URL ie. `/index/X/Y` - which means you can't rewrite this back. Two of your `RewriteRule`s have the same pattern, so the second will never match. It will always rewrite back to `page=X&value=Y` (`type` is lost).

Answer (score 3):

You can't have both the search and profile be the same regex pattern. For example, if someone requests:

```
http://example.com/index/foo
```

Are they trying to go to a page called "foo" or go to a profile of a user named "foo"? You need to add something that separates the two, maybe something like:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=profile&value=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ profile/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+)&type=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ page/%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+)(\ |$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ page/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=profile&value=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&type=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This makes your urls look like:

```
http://example.com/profile/myname

http://example.com/page/search

http://example.com/page/stats/daily
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm trying to remove the first query from the url and rewrite as the following: http://example.com/profile/myname to http://example.com/myname http://example.com/page/search to http://example.com/page/search http://example.com/page/stats/daily to http://example.com/stats/daily

Answer (score 2):

Presumably these are 3 *exceptions* (special cases) to the current rules, so the existing rules should not change. (?)

Add the following "special cases" immediately after your `RewriteBase` directive, before your existing rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=(search)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=profile&value=(myname)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=(stats)&type=(daily)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]
```

If you then need to *internally rewrite* these specific URLs back into the "real" parameterized versions then, at the end of your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(search)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(myname)$ /index.php?page=profile&value=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(stats)/(daily)$ /index.php?page=$1&type=$2 [L,QSA]
```

(I've removed the `NC` flag - add this back if you really need it.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm trying to remove the first query from the url and rewrite as the following: http://example.com/profile/myname to http://example.com/myname http://example.com/page/search to http://example.com/page/search http://example.com/page/stats/daily to http://example.com/stats/daily

Comment: Yes, that is what I think the above directives should achieve, for those 3 specific URLs as stated in your question (although the URLs stated in your comment above are different?). However, if this is intended to be a "generic" rewrite, eg. `example.com/profile/<anyname>` then this will not work as intended since it introduces an ambiguity (a one to many relationship that cannot be converted back).

Comment: But the suggested rewrite rule above doesn't seem to work. The urls listed initially won't open when applying those suggested rewrite rules.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? Does it do _anything_? These directives should work in the context given (I've also tested them on my own server to make sure). The order of these directives is important (as stated above). And it's possible that other directives in your .htaccess might conflict? Do you have anything else in your .htaccess file, apart the directives stated in your question?

Comment: Okay. Tried cleaning out the existing rules and using just yours - and it does work!

Comment: One last piece I can't figure out is how to set the value of the last param as the path name. I'm getting, http://example.com/profile rather than http://example.com/myname when using the following:

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=profile&value=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`
`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /index.php?page=profile&value=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow. You seem to be missing a `RewriteRule` directive in that code block? Note that the order of these directives is important. Your final `RewriteRule` would need to come last, but be careful of ambiguity.