# .htaccess code QSA rewrite with multiple query parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I have my .htaccess setup to redirect event pages from 
/schedule/event/?q=event-name-here
to
/schedule/event/event-name-here

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^event/(.*)$ event.php?q=$1 [QSA]
```

However, I need to add a second query parameter for the day. My new desired URL is: /schedule/event/friday/event-name-here
I tried rewriting it as such:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^event/(.*)$ event.php?day=$1&q=$2 [QSA]
```

But when I print_r($_GET); everything is in the day parameter and q is empty. $_GET['day'] is friday/event-name-here instead of being parsed into the proper parameter. I didn't find documentation, but I found a similar SA post ([.htaccess rewrite rules for multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707127/htaccess-rewrite-rules-for-multiple-parameters)) asking for almost the same thing. It looks like the same format to me. But mine is not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify two capture groups in your regular expression

```
RewriteRule ^event/((mon|tues|wednes|thurs|fri|satur|sun)day)/(.*)$ event.php?day=$1&q=$3 [QSA]
```

Note the event name is matched by the 3rd capture group. The 2nd matches the day prefix; "mon", "tues", etc.

---

You could make the 2nd group more generic at the risk of matching an invalid "day name"

```
RewriteRule ^event/([adefhimnorstuw]{3,6}day)/(.*)$ event.php?day=$1&q=$2 [QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The first solution works. I'm still pretty new to .htaccess rewrites so the syntax mostly makes sense. I'll have to read more into capture groups, now that I know what to look for!